# Existence of Optimal Policy for infinite-state MDPs

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

It is well-know from Puterman's book (1994) that in any finite-state MDP, if there exists an optimal policy, then that policy is stationary and deterministic. How about MDPs with continuous state spaces with finite-action space? Assume that the rewards are bounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the state set is Polish (e.g the set of all real numbers), finiteness of action spaces suffices to conclude that the MDP always has an optimal stationary policy - refer to "Markov Decision Processes" by Puterman for the details.